# Missing runTest function in Django app

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing

I have a simple test suite for one of the apps in my project

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
import unittest


HTTP_OK = 200
HTTP_NOTFOUND = 404


class XMLTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """docstring for XMLTestCase"""

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(XMLTestCase, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg


    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()


    def test_get_xml(self):
        response = self.client.get('get_xml', {'domain': 'sqlconnect', 'stage': 'dev'})
        self.AssertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_OK)
        self.AssertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'text/xml')


    def test_get_xml_notfound(self):
        response = self.client.get('get_xml', {'domain': 'notadomain', 'stage': 'dev'})
        self.AssertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_NOTFOUND)


    def test_upload_xml(self):
        f = open('sms_domain_sqlconnecttest.xml', 'r')
        response = self.client.post('test_upload_xml', {'xml_string': f.read, 'jobname': 'DRY_RUN'})
        self.AssertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_OK)
        self.AssertEqual(response.content, 'File was uploaded')
```

When I am running the unit tests by calling python manage.py test, this seems to fail:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 533, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(suite)
  File "/home/user/tireis/sqlconnect_ws/sqlconnect-dev/pyvenv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 494, in run_suite
    ).run(suite)
  File "/home/fds/lang/python/lib64/python3.4/unittest/runner.py", line 168, in run
    test(result)
  File "/home/fds/lang/python/lib64/python3.4/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/fds/lang/python/lib64/python3.4/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/home/fds/lang/python/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 663, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/fds/lang/python/lib64/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'XMLTestCase' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

Adding `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` won't solve this

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Does it work with Django's `TestCase`, i.e. when changing your code to the following `class XMLTestCase(TestCase):`?

Comment: @Nikita Still get the same error message. But manage.py does pick up unittest-type tests for a module I am using in my project, and these are running fine. Can it be causing this error?

Comment: I tried removing all other tests, so the fact they are based in unittest is not interfering with the django tests

Comment: @Nikita the files are in a test directory in the app path

Comment: actually the fact, that you use unittest's `TestCase` shouldn't affect `manage.py test`, as Django docs say, that one might want to use unittest's `TestCase` instead of Django's `TestCase` in some situations. The problem here is with test loader: it looks like it doesn't detect tests starting with `test_` to substitute the default `runTest` method, which is used if you want to run a single test.

Comment: btw, why do you need that `__init__` piece here?

Comment: sublimetext's original stub

Comment: Then why not remove it? You should remove it as in it's current form it prevents `unittest.TestCase` getting any constructor arguments it might require. Better, turn off this stub feature, unless you gain understanding of what it stubs.

Comment: has removing the `__init__` helped?

Comment: No, but I solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not aware that client was already an attribute to TestCase, removing the constructor call on the top of the class seems to solve the issue